# SpriteKit Scene Files: How Do I Use childNodeWithName With a Custom Subclass?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to setup my scene in my SpriteKit scene file (.sks). I set out my nodes as colored rectangles and using `childNodeWithName` works fine for deserializing into SKNode objects.

But I'm trying to deserialize into a custom subclass called BadGuyZagNode. The code builds fine but crashes at runtime.

The code:

**GameScene.m**

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    BadGuyZagNode *badGuy = (BadGuyZagNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"badguy"];
    [badGuy setupBadGuyZagNode];
}
```

**BadGuyZagNode.h**

```
@interface BadGuyZagNode : SKSpriteNode
- (void) setupBadGuyZagNode;
@end
```

**BadGuyZagNode.m**

```
@implementation BadGuyZagNode

- (void) setupBadGuyZagNode {
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.frame.size];
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = GMCollisionCategoryMinorBadGuy;
    self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = GMCollisionCategoryLaser;
    self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = GMCollisionCategoryLaser;
    self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    self.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
}

@end
```

**The error**

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SKSpriteNode setupBadGuyZagNode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Everything works if I don't use childNodeWithName and just init a spriteNodeWithColor.

I've tried adding an init method with no params and calling `[super init]` but that didn't fly.

I've reviewed both of these answers but neither applied:

[Subclassing SKNodes created with SpriteKit .sks scene file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123264/subclassing-sknodes-created-with-spritekit-sks-scene-file)

[Subclassing SpriteKit classes in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084917/subclassing-spritekit-classes-in-swift)

I've also watched the WWCD SpriteKit Best Practices video, but the examples don't use any custom classes.

Answer (score 1):

There probably isn't enough code posted to give you a more in depth answer. But the short of it is that

```
[self childNodeWithName:@"badguy"];
```

doesn't return an instance of a `BadGuyZagNode`

You can validate this by doing:

```
BadGuyZagNode *badGuy = (BadGuyZagNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"badguy"];
NSLog(@"badGuy is %@", NSStringFromClass([badGuy class]));
```

I didn't fully read [Subclassing SKNodes created with SpriteKit .sks scene file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123264/subclassing-sknodes-created-with-spritekit-sks-scene-file), but based on the question/answer, if you want to subclass `SKNode`s in the SKS, you'll need to do some work (see the answer). If you are not doing this, this is why your node is not a `BadGuyZagNode`

I'm a little unclear you mean by

> Everything works if I don't use childNodeWithName and just init a
>   spriteNodeWithColor.

How are you calling this (i.e. show more code)?

Comment: So it sounds like you're saying "It isn't possible" which is a valid answer. I didn't know enough about SpriteKit to know if it was possible.

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible. But if you are using SKS right out of the box with no additional code support, then yes. I'd read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123264/subclassing-sknodes-created-with-spritekit-sks-scene-file. Based on that it seems feasible. The way you have your stuff set up right now, it won't work, which is why you are getting the `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error.